# 'Casting' a UIView defined in Storyboard to a subclass

Tags: ios, objective-c, model-view-controller, uiview

This might be a really bad question, so I apologize in advance. Feel free to tell me if there is a better way to approach this.

I'm using storyboards to layout the initial arrangement of objects. Say that I put a `UIView` on the storyboard, and I link that view to a property in my `ViewController.m` file called `storyboardView`. At runtime, a lot might happen to that `UIView`, and following the MVC pattern, I'd like the code that governs that behavior to exist in a separate subclass. How can I 'cast' that `UIView` so that it is now responds to the subclass rather than the ViewController?

I'm thinking of something along these lines, but this doesn't work. It doesn't throw any errors, but the background color isn't turning red, so I know that I am unsuccessful:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *storyboardView;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.storyboardView = [[MyView alloc] initWithFrame:self.storyboardView.frame];
}

@end
```

Subclass Header:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyView : UIView

@end
```

Subclass Implementation:

```
import "MyView.h"

@implementation MyView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {

    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In storyboard you can change the `UIView` to any subclass like this
[image]